# How can you use MSCE with WPF 4 and Entity Framework Codefirst?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

I am attempting to create a WPF application, using MSCE and Entity Framwork. (I am new to wpf)

In asp.net mvc 3 I have done similar things simply by giving the data context, the database, and the connection string the same name.  I try that in wpf and it does not work (instead it creates a SqlExpress database.

How does one use a MSCE 4.0 database with WPF and codefirst?  Is there some sort of secret add-in?

Here is some sample code

in the app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ReportingContext" connectionString="provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ReportingContext.sdf" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

from the models folder

```
public class ReportingContext : DbContext
    {
     ...
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that's creating this database (i.e. that works with ASP.NET MVC and not with WPF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the nuget packages somehow.  I deleted all of them, reinstalled and the problem vanished.